# Programmatically changing size of 1 subview in UIStackView

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

I am currently making a calculator and want to change the size of my `0` button to the size of 2 subviews - which is half the size of the entire view. I want it to look exactly like apples calculator app, where the `0` is bigger than all the other buttons.
The way i layout my view is by having a vertical `UIStackView` and adding horizontal `UIStackView`'s to it, just like the picture below.
[image]

Therefore, i want the last horizontal stack to have 3 arranged subviews but make the `0` button fill the exceeding space, so the `,` and `=` buttons are the same size as all other buttons.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Programmatically**, you could set multiplier with `constraint(equalTo:multiplier:)`, official docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutdimension/1500951-constraint

So we could constraint the last two button with same width and make the first one two times longer than one of the other two.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        view.backgroundColor = .white

        let btn1 = UIButton()
        let btn2 = UIButton()
        let btn3 = UIButton()

        btn1.backgroundColor = .red
        btn2.backgroundColor = .yellow
        btn3.backgroundColor = .blue

        let hStack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [btn1, btn2, btn3])
        hStack.axis = .horizontal
        hStack.spacing = 1

        view.addSubview(hStack)
        hStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        hStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        hStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        hStack.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

        // Here would be what you need:
        btn2.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: btn3.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        btn1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: btn2.widthAnchor, multiplier: 2).isActive = true
    }
```

[image]

Comment: I used your approach a little differently to fix my problem. My stackview are layoutet by using autolayout, and i didnt have access to any of my previous generated buttons, as i use a loop to generate them. Therefore, i wanted to set the button width by using the `UIStackView` frame width. My problem was that the frame wasn't calculated when viewDidLoad were called. Therefore i would set the buttons width to 0. The solution was to layout my views in `layoutSubviews()`, here the frame was calculated and therefore i could access the width.

Comment: @SørenGade btw, you try to set a ```lazy var```

Comment: I don't get it, use a lazy var for what? Every variable and view will eventually be calculated anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can use stackview.distribution = .fillEquallly for first 4 horizontal stackviews and use stackview.distribution = .fillPropotionally for the last horizontal stackview.

Then set with constraint for the 0 button to 50% of last horizontal stackview's width.

[image]

[image]

[image]